# Looking to make a discord bot on mac, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Not really sure why this isn't running.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/diyar/Desktop/myBot/test-myBot.py", line 3, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Comment: Hello! For security reasons, you should not paste the actual token of yours into the snippet you provide here, because now everybody who seen this post can do things with your bot. I suggest that you regenerate your token just in case.

Answer (score 3):

The Client constructor requires you to pass an intents, as you can see in the discord.py docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client#client). Intents tell the Discord API which events to send to your application, you can read more about this [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#:%7E:text=Intents%20are%20bitwise%20values%20that,listed%20in%20the%20intents%20section.).

From the [Quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) section on the docs, replacing `client = discord.Client()` with something like this should fix the problem:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

I also highly recommend that you **remove the application token from your question and reset it from the Discord developer interface asap**, because the token you posted is now freely available on the internet, which means that **anyone** can use it.